# Delete row contains partial date type type string

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

In my database there is a column named datetime:

```
open    high    low     close   volume  datetime

282.38  282.74  282.35  282.69  178326  2020-04-16 15:54:00.000
282.69  282.82  282.37  282.82  107392  2020-04-16 15:55:00.000
```

Now I want to delete all the rows where datetime contains **2020-04-16 15**

Code:

```
DELETE
FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
WHERE datetime LIKE '%2020-04-16 15%'
```

or Code:

```
DELETE
FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
WHERE CONTAINS (datetime,'2020-04-16 15')
```

Result:

> Msg 7601, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
>   Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view 'database.dbo.table' because it is not full-text indexed.
>   Completion time: 2020-04-16T16:50:22.8126553-05:00

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your datetime column is of datetime datatype (because otherwise your first attempt will work), then you can't use `like` with this format because its not stored as a string.

And `contains` is only for a full text index - which a datetime column is not.

Try using a datetime window e.g.

```
DELETE
FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
WHERE datetime >= '2020-04-16 15:00:00.000'
AND datetime < '2020-04-16 16:00:00.000';
```

Update from Martin Smith: You can use `like` against a datetime column, it will just be implicitly converted to a `varchar` with style `0` so would need to use a pattern like `Apr 16 2020 3:%PM` for English language. But of course not a good idea for multiple reasons.